# How to check file extension in laravel post request? mycodetest

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code it is working but I want the best practice

```
 if(Input::hasFile('note_thumb')) {

            $file = Input::file('note_thumb');
            $fileName = substr($file->getClientOriginalName(), -4);
            if ($fileName == '.jpg' || $fileName == 'jpeg' || $fileName == '.png') {
                //is image
                //return 'maaz';
                $finalpath = "";
                $file = Input::file('note_thumb');
                $tmpFilePath = '/notes/thumnail/';
                $tmpFileName = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $tmpFileName = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $tmpFileName);
                $file = $file->move(public_path() . $tmpFilePath, $tmpFileName);
                $path = $tmpFileName;
                $finalpath .= $path;
                /*if ($i != $count_file - 1) {
                    $finalpath .= ',';
                }*/

                $newNote->note_thumb = $finalpath;
            }
```

Comment: $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); have you tried this?

Comment: For code reviews there is an [own topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) within the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$extension = $request->note_thumb->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

From the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests